# How do I make sure data in my SparkStream app isn't lost when save() fails?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, databricks, spark-streaming, spark-cassandra-connector

I have a spark readStream function which reads from Kafka continuously. I perform few manipulations on the data and wanted to write it to Cassandra DB using a Spark writeStream in batches. While been writing to Cassandra, It might throw any kind of exceptions(ConnectionTimeOut etc.,). What can I do to make sure that the data isn't been lost and what can I do to perform a retry on that specific batch of data.

This is my writeStream function which internally call the save method where we perform a write into the table.

```
query = df.writeStream \
    .outputMode("append") \
    .option("checkpointLocation", "path") \
    .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \  
    .option("maxAttempts", "5") \ 
    .option("retryOnDataLoss", "true") \ 
    .option("failedWriteFile", "path") \
    .foreachBatch(save) \
    .start()
```

And this is the save method.

```
`def save(df, batch_id):
    try:
        (df.write
         .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
         .options(table=tableName, keyspace=keyspaceName)
         .mode("append")
         .save())
        return None
    except Exception as e:
        raise e`
```

as far as I think, when a exception is been thrown from the save method the spark function retries that batch again until the retries are exhausted. And even if it still fails it would write into specified path and continues the process for next batch.

Are those options `maxAttempts`, `retryOnDataLoss`, `failedWriteFile`, are still valid? I haven't found any reference on the official sparkDocs or else anything in the spark-cassandra-connector lib.
Or there are any other alternatives.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#foreachbatch

Answer (score 0):

The Spark Cassandra connector will [retry the `save()` 60 times by default](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/v3.3.0/doc/reference.md#cassandra-connection-parameters):

```
spark.cassandra.query.retry.count   60
```

unless you override the property in your application's configuration.

If the writes to Cassandra fail after 60 attempts, I would suggest that data loss is going to the least of your problems because your Cassandra is most likely down. Cheers!